# Since updating to iOS 17, my AirPods Pro (2nd generation) start at very low volume when I connect them. How do I fix this?

Tags: iphone, ios, airpods

Every time I connect them, no matter what my phone’s volume is set to, my AirPods Pro starts at low volume when I first connect them, and I have to turn them up before I can really hear them.

This makes it where I have to ask people to repeat themselves on phone calls and I have to seek backward on songs to hear what I missed.

- I didn’t have this problem before the iOS 17 update.
- I am using an iPhone 12.
- I’m not aware of any setting that would control this

Is there something I can do so the volume is preserved between each use?

Comment: Have you checked Settings > Sounds & Haptics > Headphone Safety > HEADPHONE NOTIFICATIONS to see if the iPhone volume has been turned down? You may have missed the notification. Tap the Learn more ... link.

Comment: @IconDaemon My phone says there are 0 headphone notifications.